# In MVC3, how to get the current controller name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, namespaces, controller, httpcontext

From the http context class is there a method to get the current Controller name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like that

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

If you're in a view, then you can do:

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]
```